# Ribbon buttons act like a group

Tags: delphi, button, ribbon

I created 3 actions and assigned them to 3 buttons in a ribbon group. I want the buttons act like a group, one is always down, the others - up. Just like left/center/right align buttons.

I have set groupIndex property of my actions to 1. Help says:
"GroupIndex is used to define groups of actions that act like radio buttons. When GroupIndex is greater than 0, it identifies the group to which the action belongs. When the Checked property of any action in that group is set to true, the Checked property of all other actions in the group is set to false. That is, only one action in the group can be checked at a time."

But it is not working at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information the only thing I can suggest is (if you are using `tdxRibbon`) is to check and make sure the `buttonstyle` property is set to `bsChecked`. Although it shouldn't let you set the group index otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the property `AutoCheck = true` for both items. It helped me =)